# Hadith about wife licking pus of husband authentic?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Is this hadith authentic about the rights of husbands over wives and if she was to lick the pus and sores from him she she still wouldn't fulfill her rights?

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “It is not right for any human being to prostrate to another; if it were right for one human being to prostrate to another, I would have commanded women to prostrate to their husbands because of the great rights that they have over them. By the One in Whose hand is my soul, if a man were covered from head to foot with weeping sores oozing pus, and his wife were to come to him and lick his sores (to clean them), this would not fulfil the rights he has over her.’” (Reported by Imaam Ahmad, 12153; Saheeh al-Jaami’, 7725).

https://islamqa.info/en/4601

Answer (score 4):

Seems that there is some difference in opinion on its authenticity. Al Albani viewed it as sound but others disagree. Among them who disagree is the Islamweb team.

Their answer [(click here to read)](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=335095) answers the question pretty thoroughly. In summary: Likely it is not authentic but nevertheless, it is just emphasizing the great rights husband has over his wife.

It definitely is not saying that wives ought to lick the impurities from their husband clean. It's just literary exaggeration to make a point.

Comment: I agree. It's literary exaggeration to make a point. It means, even in that case... He still have rights over her.